# Nginx - Server dead when received many requests

Tags: php, nginx, google-cloud-platform, caching, centos

we have a large Woocommerce website hosted on Google VM servers (E2 4vCPU + 16 GB RAM + 100 GB SSD Storage), recently we created a mobile application using flutter and WordPress -Woocommerce- API, but we faced a three issues

1. if two users open the app at the same time, data loading synchronously not parallel, it seems the server dealing with a single request only at the same time
2. fetching data is very slow, to load a product maybe it will take more than 5 seconds on a HighSpeed Internet connection
3. if the user using the app the website will take more time to load, it seems the server dealing with a single request only at the same time

Environment Details

- server NGINX + MySQL + PHP-FPM
- PHP 7.4
- OS: Centos 8
- All tables Engin - InnoDB

we did the following

- increased PHP.ini memory limit to 15GB
- increased PHP.ini timeout limit to 3000 sec
- Linked website with cloudflare. - Installed Cache Plugin W3 Total Cache
- Increase NGINX MAX Clients to 150

I am looking for a suggestion on how I can allow to server/MySQL handle a lot of requests?

PHP-FPM Config

```
pm.max_children = 200
pm.start_servers = 50
pm.min_spare_servers = 50
pm.max_spare_servers = 150
;pm.max_requests = 500
;php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 128M
;request_terminate_timeout = 0
;rlimit_core = 0
;rlimit_files = 1024
;pm.process_idle_timeout = 10s;
;pm.max_requests = 500
pm = dynamic
; process.priority = -19
```

PHP ini

```
;user_ini.cache_ttl = 300
implicit_flush = Off
;unserialize_max_depth = 4096
;realpath_cache_size = 4096k
;realpath_cache_ttl = 120
zend.exception_ignore_args = On
max_input_time = 6000
max_execution_time = 3000
;max_input_nesting_level = 64
memory_limit = 15000M
post_max_size = 800M
;mysqlnd.mempool_default_size = 16000
;mysqlnd.net_read_timeout = 31536000
;mysqlnd.net_cmd_buffer_size = 2048
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled=1
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl=86400
```

PHP-FPM www-status, when the app opening

```
pool:                 www
process manager:      ondemand
start time:           03/Feb/2023:11:59:36 +0000
start since:          25801
accepted conn:        14613
listen queue:         0
max listen queue:     0
listen queue len:     0
idle processes:       0
active processes:     20
total processes:      20
max active processes: 20
max children reached: 53
slow requests:        0

************************
pid:                  14270
state:                Running
start time:           03/Feb/2023:19:08:39 +0000
start since:          58
requests:             17
request duration:     563199
request method:       GET
request URI:          /index.php?consumer_key=xxx&consumer_secret=yyy
content length:       0
user:                 -
script:               /var/www/mydomain.com/html/index.php
last request cpu:     0.00
last request memory:  0

************************
pid:                  14272
state:                Running
start time:           03/Feb/2023:19:09:03 +0000
start since:          34
requests:             12
request duration:     267198
request method:       GET
request URI:          /index.php
content length:       0
user:                 -
script:               /var/www/mydomain.com/html/index.php
last request cpu:     0.00
last request memory:  0

************************
pid:                  14273
state:                Finishing
start time:           03/Feb/2023:19:09:03 +0000
start since:          34
requests:             7
request duration:     5577206
request method:       GET
request URI:          /index.php?consumer_key=xxx&consumer_secret=yyy
content length:       0
user:                 -
script:               /var/www/mydomain.com/html/index.php
last request cpu:     0.00
last request memory:  0

************************
pid:                  14274
state:                Running
start time:           03/Feb/2023:19:09:03 +0000
start since:          34
requests:             7
request duration:     2475191
request method:       GET
request URI:          /index.php?consumer_key=xx&consumer_secret=yyy
content length:       0
user:                 -
script:               /var/www/mydomain.com/html/index.php
last request cpu:     0.00
last request memory:  0

************************
pid:                  14275
state:                Running
start time:           03/Feb/2023:19:09:03 +0000
start since:          34
requests:             8
request duration:     2731158
request method:       GET
request URI:          /index.php?status=publish&category=189&orderby=popularity&per_page=5&consumer_key=xxx&consumer_secret=yy
content length:       0
user:                 -
script:               /var/www/mydomain.com/html/index.php
last request cpu:     0.00
last request memory:  0

************************
pid:                  14276
state:                Running
start time:           03/Feb/2023:19:09:04 +0000
start since:          33
requests:             8
request duration:     934026
request method:       GET
request URI:          /index.php?consumer_key=xxx&consumer_secret=yyy
content length:       0
user:                 -
script:               /var/www/mydomain.com/html/index.php
last request cpu:     0.00
last request memory:  0

************************
pid:                  14277
state:                Running
start time:           03/Feb/2023:19:09:07 +0000
start since:          30
requests:             6
request duration:     3243188
request method:       GET
request URI:          /index.php?consumer_key=xxx&consumer_secret=yyy
content length:       0
user:                 -
script:               /var/www/mydomain.com/html/index.php
last request cpu:     0.00
last request memory:  0

************************
pid:                  14278
state:                Finishing
start time:           03/Feb/2023:19:09:07 +0000
start since:          30
requests:             6
request duration:     5822217
request method:       GET
request URI:          /index.php?consumer_key=xx&consumer_secret=yyy
content length:       0
user:                 -
script:               /var/www/mydomain.com/html/index.php
last request cpu:     0.00
last request memory:  0

************************
pid:                  14279
state:                Running
start time:           03/Feb/2023:19:09:07 +0000
start since:          30
requests:             7
request duration:     220
request method:       GET
request URI:          /www-status?full
content length:       0
user:                 -
script:               -
last request cpu:     0.00
last request memory:  0

************************
pid:                  14280
state:                Running
start time:           03/Feb/2023:19:09:07 +0000
start since:          30
requests:             6
request duration:     5309224
request method:       GET
request URI:          /index.php?status=publish&per_page=20&page=1&skip_cache=1&stock_status=instock&consumer_key=xxx&consumer_secret=yy
content length:       0
user:                 -
script:               /var/www/mydomain.com/html/index.php
last request cpu:     0.00
last request memory:  0

************************
pid:                  14281
state:                Running
start time:           03/Feb/2023:19:09:07 +0000
start since:          30
requests:             7
request duration:     2048190
request method:       GET
request URI:          /index.php?consumer_key=xx&consumer_secret=yyy
content length:       0
user:                 -
script:               /var/www/mydomain.com/html/index.php
last request cpu:     0.00
last request memory:  0

************************
pid:                  14282
state:                Running
start time:           03/Feb/2023:19:09:07 +0000
start since:          30
requests:             6
request duration:     5482457
request method:       GET
request URI:          /index.php?consumer_key=xx&consumer_secret=yy
content length:       0
user:                 -
script:               /var/www/mydomain.com/html/index.php
last request cpu:     0.00
last request memory:  0

************************
pid:                  14283
state:                Running
start time:           03/Feb/2023:19:09:07 +0000
start since:          30
requests:             6
request duration:     5262082
request method:       GET
request URI:          /index.php?consumer_key=xx&consumer_secret=yy
content length:       0
user:                 -
script:               /var/www/mydomain.com/html/index.php
last request cpu:     0.00
last request memory:  0

************************
pid:                  14288
state:                Running
start time:           03/Feb/2023:19:09:07 +0000
start since:          30
requests:             7
request duration:     330128
request method:       GET
request URI:          /index.php?per_page=100&page=1&per_page=10&consumer_key=xxx&consumer_secret=yy
content length:       0
user:                 -
script:               /var/www/mydomain.com/html/index.php
last request cpu:     0.00
last request memory:  0

************************
pid:                  14291
state:                Running
start time:           03/Feb/2023:19:09:07 +0000
start since:          30
requests:             6
request duration:     4372096
request method:       GET
request URI:          /index.php?consumer_key=xxx&consumer_secret=yyy
content length:       0
user:                 -
script:               /var/www/mydomain.com/html/index.php
last request cpu:     0.00
last request memory:  0

************************
pid:                  14293
state:                Running
start time:           03/Feb/2023:19:09:10 +0000
start since:          27
requests:             6
request duration:     710233
request method:       GET
request URI:          /index.php?consumer_key=xxx&consumer_secret=yyy
content length:       0
user:                 -
script:               /var/www/mydomain.com/html/index.php
last request cpu:     0.00
last request memory:  0

************************
pid:                  14296
state:                Running
start time:           03/Feb/2023:19:09:12 +0000
start since:          25
requests:             5
request duration:     4356106
request method:       GET
request URI:          /index.php?consumer_key=xxx&consumer_secret=yyy
content length:       0
user:                 -
script:               /var/www/mydomain.com/html/index.php
last request cpu:     0.00
last request memory:  0

************************
pid:                  14297
state:                Running
start time:           03/Feb/2023:19:09:13 +0000
start since:          24
requests:             5
request duration:     3993473
request method:       GET
request URI:          /index.php?consumer_key=xxx&consumer_secret=yyy
content length:       0
user:                 -
script:               /var/www/mydomain.com/html/index.php
last request cpu:     0.00
last request memory:  0

************************
pid:                  14299
state:                Running
start time:           03/Feb/2023:19:09:15 +0000
start since:          22
requests:             4
request duration:     5846079
request method:       GET
request URI:          /index.php?status=publish&category=190&orderby=popularity&per_page=5&consumer_key=xxx&consumer_secret=yyy
content length:       0
user:                 -
script:               /var/www/mydomain.com/html/index.php
last request cpu:     0.00
last request memory:  0

************************
pid:                  14269
state:                Running
start time:           03/Feb/2023:19:08:37 +0000
start since:          60
requests:             15
request duration:     355854
request method:       GET
request URI:          /index.php?consumer_key=xxx&consumer_secret=yyy
content length:       0
user:                 -
script:               /var/www/mydomain.com/html/index.php
last request cpu:     0.00
last request memory:  0
```

Comment: What does the Lighthouse feature in Chrome devtools tell you? What does the Query Monitor plugin tell you? Is your MySql server overburdened? Sounds like it to me.  Paradoxically, sometimes *reducing* concurrency (reducing max clients) can improve responsiveness and request throughput.

Comment: You php process looks too high for your CPUs and you don't inform any MySQL configuration. You can use php-fpm slow log or xdebug + kcachegrind to analyze the profile data as explained in https://xdebug.org/docs/profiler.

Comment: "loading synchronously" -- please provide details of what is loaded and how.  If it is MySQL, provide the SQL and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: I added PHP-PFM Status @RickJames

Comment: Please add `SHOW PROCESSLIST` (preferrably without the "Sleep" entries).

Answer (score 1):

First of all make sure your FPM-CONFIG is actually read

you have set `pm.max_children` to `200` , and with a `memory_limit` of 15GB

to have this config, you better have more than 3000GB of RAM (200 x 15GB/15000M) - which you dont.

My suggestion is -

reduce max memory usage to `512`MB
php.ini

```
memory_limit = 512M
```

fpm-config -

set PM to ondemand

```
pm=ondemand
pm.max_children = 20
pm.start_servers = 4
pm.min_spare_servers = 5
pm.max_spare_servers = 10
pm.process_idle_timeout = 10
```

Debugging further

add this to fpm-config

```
pm.status_path = /www-status
```

nginx conf - (you might need to adjust this to fit yours)

```
        location ~ ^/(www-status)$ {
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000; # replace this or use the unix socket
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME 
                $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
```

head onto site.com/www-status and youll see the fpm usage info, with this you can find out how much you actually need.

also try to use Nginx caching, this will be a huge help for your server
use NGINX cahing - https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/content-cache/content-caching

Comment: Thanks for your effort, I did all your steps but still facing the same issue can you help me more? I added www-status on the question please check it @janithcooray

Comment: see the part that says `max children reached`, this means the maximum capacity has been reached 53 times. you seem to be getting 1.7 connections / user vists on average per second. so about 6.5K visitors an hour. you can further reduce your memory limit to 128MB and set `max_children` to `80`. if that doesn’t work your only options are 1. Increase vCPUs ,2. Increase Caching, 3.Increase Server RAM and max_children, 4. Add another server as a load balanced setup.

Comment: also this question belongs to serverfault, best move it before this gets downvoted and removed.